# How to use system.out.println when using a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jira-plugin

I want to debug a program by using `system.out.println()` and what to
 check the flow and variables value in eclipse while running a JIRA
 plugin which is a Servlet . 
 When I make some changes to the code in eclipse it reflects on the
 browser but when I use `system.out.println` where should i see the
 output ?

Example Code :

```
    @RequiresXsrfCheck
    protected String doExecute()
    {   

        LOG.info("BulkCloneDetails doExecute start...");
        filterUrl = null;
        cloneSubTasks = false;
        cloneAttachments = false;
        deleteAfterClone = false;
        requestId = null;
        issues = null;
        getServerInfoFromPage();  

        **System.out.println("Print something here");**

        errorsCollection.put("filterPath", i18n.getText("Remote login failed"));
        addErrors(errorsCollection);
        return SUCCESS;

    }
```

Comment: In the eclipse console, no?..

Comment: How do you run your plugin? Do you have a installation of jira with some app server/etc?

Comment: @dbf I run the plugin using atlas-run in console and when I make changes I use FastDev to update the local instance of Jira in my PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a tail on a file in Terminal so that you can see how it is interacted with. On a webapp I am working on I use the below method.

```
Username$ cd /Applications/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/logs
```

Then type

```
tail –f catalina.out
```

This will then print to your Terminal window. I have had to use this method on a few projects. I advise you to use `system.out.println("Name of the File I am printing from")` so that if you have several of such then you will know where they are coming from and in what order.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you will be having a number of console options and one would be for Apache Tomcat.

Switch to that console window for observing your messages.

Hope This helps.